# Whats wrong with the .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is **wrong** with this Code?

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var div=$("#oarm2");
    div.animate({marginTop:'150px', transform:'skew(15deg, -60deg)'},"slow");
});
```

When I press the button, an div Element should be go down in the Page and change the Form.

The "marginTop" is functionally, but the transform skew not..

What is wrong? How I must write this?

Comment: Coud you please create a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ ? Makes it easier to correct your code.

Comment: You may also directly use a CSS transition or animation (in contrast to that JS animation…)

Comment: Yes, wait an Moment ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate element transform rotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958873/jquery-animate-a-webkit-transform

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDFmt/1/)</kbd>

**Js**

```
$("#go").click(function(){    
     $("#oarm2").animate({marginTop:'150px', transform:'skew(15deg, -60deg)'},"slow"); });
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
<div id="oarm2">Hello!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background-color: #bca;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
```

Here I include jquery library file **`jquery-1.8.3.js`**

Comment: thank you ;) top works, but skew not

Comment: To use skew and other CSS transitions I can reccomend [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

Comment: nice! Transit works fine and is short! Thanks